# Laravel resource policy always false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to allow user to view their own profile in Laravel 5.4.

**UserPolicy.php**

```
public function view(User $authUser, $user)
{ 
 return true;
}
```

**registered policy in AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $policies = [
    App\Task::class => App\Policies\TaskPolicy::class,
    App\User::class => App\Policies\UserPolicy::class
];
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
  Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
} );
```

**Blade template**

```
@can ( 'view', $user )
// yes
@else
// no
@endcan
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->show(Auth::user()->id);
}
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('user.show', array( 'user'=>$user,'data'=>$this->data ) );
}
```

The return is always 'false'. Same for calling policy form the controller. Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question feels weird, but I hate it when I come across questions without followups.

So after double checking It turned out that if I remove [authorizeResource](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesResources.html#method_authorizeResource) from the constructor:

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->authorizeResource(User::class);
  }
```

and check for authorization in the controller function:

```
  $this->authorize('view',$user);
```

everything works.
I must've missed this part when I added `$user` as a parameter in the policy function. So the user to be viewed is never passed in the `authorizeResource` method.

Thanks everyone for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Don't feel bad for answering your own questions, It's a really appreciated way to enrich the contents of this site and help others.

Answer (score 2):

When you add

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->authorizeResource(User::class);
}
```

to your Controller, you have to edit all your function signatures to match it to the class e.g. your show signature has to change from `public function show($id)`
to `public function show(User $user)`

After that it should work

Comment: The problem with this answer is that Laravel checks the gate/policy *before* it tries to run the controller method. In my case, it doesn't appear to be checking the policy at all for policy points that have a model. Those that don't have a model work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just a different approach here to users viewing their own profile.

First, I will create a route for that

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('profile', 'UserController@profile');
});
```

Then in the `profile` function I do

```
public function profile()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('profile', compact('user'));
}
```

This way, user automatically only views their own profile.

Now, if you want to allow some users to view others' profiles, then you can use Policy. Why? Because I think user should ALWAYS be able to view their own profile. But not all users should view other users profiles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I'm tyring to allow a parent user to view/edit his own profile **and** his child users profiles (like a boss and his employees). So the employee can only view his own profile, and the boss can only view/edit his employees and not other boss' employees. I simplyfied my example, because the actual question is why this function from my policy file returns `false`, even though I wrote `return true;`

Comment: Then try to redefine your policy like `public function view(User $parent, User $user)`; Not sure if it will make a difference though. But nothing to loose in trying.

Comment: Nope. Also tried rewriting blade template like `@if (Auth::user()->can('view', $user))`. I don't think there's anything wrong with the syntax.

Comment: `@cannnot('view',$user)` also gives me `This action is unauthorized.`

Comment: Usually when something is not working for me, I actually look for a work around. Comes to think of it. You don't want user to view other boss' employees. Using `@can()` in the view means you already display the page to them. I think you shouldn't even display the page. Therefore, you can do a quick check in the controller and redirect them to home page if they are not authorize. That one should be easier.

Comment: I agree the authorization must best be check in the controller. But my policy doesn't work in the controller either. I just thought that using policies would speed me up, looks like it doesn't :) I'll check everything again and if doesn't work, go back to putting everything to `Gate::define` for every action.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Change the second parameter from `@can( 'view', $user )` to `@can( 'view', $subject )` and it will work find.

**Why:**

Because you're doing it the wrong way.

```
public function view(User $user, $subject){ 
 return true;
}
```

Just look carefully the policy view method, first parameter is `authenticated user` or `current user` and second parameter is `$subject`, Since policies organize authorization logic around models.

> Policies are classes that organize authorization logic around a
>   particular model or resource. For example, if your application is a
>   blog, you may have a Post model and a corresponding PostPolicy to
>   authorize user actions such as creating or updating posts.

if you want to go further deep inside it.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L353

```
/**
 * Resolve the callback for a policy check.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  string  $ability
 * @param  array  $arguments
 * @return callable
 */
protected function resolvePolicyCallback($user, $ability, array $arguments)
{
    return function () use ($user, $ability, $arguments) {
        $instance = $this->getPolicyFor($arguments[0]);

        // If we receive a non-null result from the before method, we will return it
        // as the final result. This will allow developers to override the checks
        // in the policy to return a result for all rules defined in the class.
        if (method_exists($instance, 'before')) {
            if (! is_null($result = $instance->before($user, $ability, ...$arguments))) {
                return $result;
            }
        }

        if (strpos($ability, '-') !== false) {
            $ability = Str::camel($ability);
        }

        // If the first argument is a string, that means they are passing a class name
        // to the policy. We will remove the first argument from this argument list
        // because the policy already knows what type of models it can authorize.
        if (isset($arguments[0]) && is_string($arguments[0])) {
            array_shift($arguments);
        }

        if (! is_callable([$instance, $ability])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $instance->{$ability}($user, ...$arguments);
    };
}
```

See the last line where it is calling the method with $user and $argument( in our case Model ) is passed.

[Laravel Docs for Authorization/Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably my parameter names were misleading, sorry about that. What I wanted is to pass `authenticated user` as the first parameter and the user to be viewed as the second one. I edited my answer to show that I pass `$user` from my controller, and then I use the same variable name in my blade `@can( 'view', $user )`. `$user` (previously called `$subject`) is the user to be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to escape one or more policies methods using options parameter at authorizeResource with except:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->authorizeResource(User::class, 'user', ['except' => ['view']]);
}
```

This should be on Laravel's documentation, but it isn't. I discovered this just guessing. I think this way it is a better approach thus, by removing `authorizeResource` method in the `construct`, it would be necessary to implement the `authorization` method for each resource action in order to protect the controller.