# Laravel 5.5, can't handle policy/authorization exception on constructor

Tags: laravel, authorization

This is part of my `PostCategoriesController` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\PostCategory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class PostCategoriesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            echo 'The try works.';
            $this->authorizeResource(PostCategoriesController::class);
        } catch (\Exception $err) {
            // Never get here.
            dd('The catch does not. We never see this...');
        }
    }


    public function create()
    {
        // This works... but then I have to repeat it for every action...
        try {
            $this->authorize('create');
            return view('admin.post-categories.create');
        } catch (\Exception $err) {
           //return redirect()->route('admin.welcome');
           return 'You cannot create categories, sorry.';
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is specifically with the method `authorizeResource()`, which throws the exception:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   AccessDeniedHttpException This action is unauthorized.

The method `authorizeResource()` not on the docs but I see it recommended in some other posts, like  [Laravel policy always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076895/laravel-policy-always-false/42085613#42085613) and [Apply Policy to Resource Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501430/apply-policy-to-resource-controller/44501939#44501939) for example. It is also [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a8130c7e4ff2888b3949751259b45f287bf518a0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L83).

The `PostCategoryPolicy` class just returns booleans from he methods, things like:

```
public function update(User $user, PostCategory $postCategory)
{
    return $user->has_role === 1;
}
```

So, why can't I catch that exception?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue, based on my own requirement I applied a particular solution that works fine for me, hope it works for you as well

This is more of a generic way to handle this exception, rather than specific to each controller or method inside controller

Please refer to this file

`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exception/Handler.php`

inside this file you'll see a protected function

```
protected function prepareResponse($request, Exception $e)
```

you need to override this function in your own Handler.php file that can be found inside

`/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

just override this function and try to handle Synfony Access Denied Exception, I simply copy pasted the entire code and added my own little code right before final return so that everything else works as it was working earlier, the only thing changes is how AccessDenied exception is handled

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

protected function prepareResponse($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException) {
        // $this->unauthorized is a custom & local function that I created
        // you can try doing dd('yes it works over here');
        return $this->unauthorized($request, $e);
    }
}
```

I have simply tried to explain you the concept, you can replace the line

return $this->unauthorized($request, $e);

with any kind of Laravel code you need, like redirect, dd etc

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help. I won't be able to test this now but I'll keep it in mind for when I have some other work to do in the project where this problem occurred.

Comment: This removes too much of the parent function to be useful. Exceptions that are not an `AccessDeniedHttpException` will be ignored and returned void.

Comment: using `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException` is not working instead i use `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException`